# Rails 3: Should I create a table just for one record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've run into this problem a few times where I'm creating a CMS and there's one part of the site that will never need more than one record (like contact info or homepage description). Perhaps it also has a hero image or something. This section needs to be editable by the admin.

Should I create a contact_infos table just for this one record and create a record manually and restrict the CMS so that you can only edit/update that one record? Just asking to see if there are any cleaner solutions, because a whole table for 1 record seems like a big commitment.

Comment: Depending on who will update the Contact infos and how he could access to the site, you could use the gem FrozenRecord: https://github.com/byroot/frozen_record . It is an ActiveRecord-like system but based on YAML static files, not based on a real DataBase. With this, to update the content of Contact Infos the guy would have to modify the YAML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple model and a single table? Do it. You might need one today, and then later, another, in which case you're already set.

Comment: Agreed; it also allows you to view a history of changes to that data, plus freedom to implement other data, such as some sort of "changed_by" user id relation, etc.